# Can anyone tell me what species this baby bird this is?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

Can anyone tell me what species this baby bird this is? He or she is less than two weeks old. Fell out of nest. He is doing well. I live in Sacramento Ca, Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Looks like possibly a baby starling to me

Comment: whatever it is, it probably needs feeding in the same instructions as a baby blackbird or a starling, i.e. every few hours, hard work.